# Adobe Echosign: Is it possible to get Documents by Name?

Tags: adobe, echosign

We have an EchoSign account with lots of documents in it. We now need to retrieve the documents from another application and would like to use the SOAP or REST API for it. I have an API key and managed to get the SOAP API working. Unfortunately I did not find a way do retrieve documents by their name? The creator of the documents did not provide an externalID.

Answer (score 0):

I got some responses on this issue from Adobe support:

1. The external ID needs to be set at the time of creating the documents, and cannot be set later on.
2. Only way to get a document by name is to use the `getUsersInAccount` request to retrieve a set of all users, then use the `getUserDocuments` request for each user, then scan the names in the `DocumentsListItems` and finally retrieve the document using the documentKey.